# Ativar o jQuery Validate (plugin) com a resposta do ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

Eu sempre achei interessante este plugin, pois deixa o formulário simples com mensagens sutis ao visitante. Resolvi implementar e cai no seguinte dilema:

Como eu faço para o retorno do meu AJAX ativar algum aviso no meu formulário? por exemplo:

Tenho um input simples com o nome do usuário, com min-lenght de 2. Caso eu coloque 1 caracter apenas, ele vai ativar e avisar que precisa ter 2, mas e caso eu precise fazer uma requisição ajax para o meu servidor e verificar se este nome já existe no meu banco de dados?

Caso exista, ele procede normal, caso não, mostra o erro (igual com o min-lenght)

meu código atual:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

var validator = $("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Preencha o nome",
            minlength: "Minimo: 2 caracter"
        }
    }
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       $("#contactform").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "form.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    if (result.status == "OK") {
                        // aqui está tudo certo e aparece um aviso
                    }else{
                        // ESSA É A DÚVIDA: caso o nome exista, ele ativa o input com a mensagem de retorno
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
         });
    },
});
});
```

Comment: dê uma olhada na minha resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O plugin jQuery Validate possui uma funcionalidade chamada **remote method**, onde o mesmo executa uma requisição para checar a validade do elemento.

No seu caso, ficaria mais ou menos assim para realizar a validação do lado do servidor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

var validator = $("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            remote: {
               url: 'validate.php'.
               type: 'post',
               data: { name: $('#name').val() }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Preencha o nome",
            minlength: "Minimo: 2 caracter"
        }
    }
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       // removido para ter brevidade
    },
});
});
```

Sendo que seu método pode retornar uma mensagem em forma de string que será exibida como mensagem de validação para o campo.

Mais informações podem ser encontradas no link https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, obrigado!